# How can I create a collapsing animation using different views in a toolbar?

Tags: android, animation, scroll, toolbar

How can I create a collapsing animation using different views in a Toolbar?

I would like to create an animation similar to what happens when you collapse the toolbar of a Whatsapp group as you can see in the images.

[image: Toolbar expanded]

[image: Toolbar collapsed]
As you can see, the toolbar is formed by some views. I guess that they are childs of the Toolbar.
I have been trying to create the same effect moving all the views when you scroll but I am only able to move the title of the Toolbar, not the other views. Any suggestion? What components do I need to use and how?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few components you can try to achieve what you are looking for. `CoordinatorLayout` offers some built-in basic animations when interacting with `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Check out some examples in the [Material Design components site](https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-top).

If you want something more complex you can try using `MotionLayout`, there are some good guides over the web but [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d) series of articles gives a good introduction.